# How can I prompt user for more information during sign-in/registration process with Firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I am using the firebaseUI toolset to allow users to login to my app.
I'm also using the firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged method to redirect them to the main application once they are logged in.

What I would like to do is, during the sign-in process...if they are a new user, prompt them for a displayname to use (to override whatever name is given by the 3rd party provider).

Right now, once they login, they are redirected to the app..and it's not obvious how I can have a smooth workflow that would provide a modal /screen to allow them to create  a display name before continuing onto the app.

Is there a recommended best practice of how to capture/prompt for additional information during the first sign-in process, which I would then store in my firebase /users collection?

Right now it will just auto redirect to the main app.

```
    componentDidMount() {
    //console.log(this.props.isLoading)
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        if(user) {

            this.props.setUser(user);
            this.props.history.push('/');

        } 


  callbacks : {
    signInSuccessWithAuthResult: function(authResult, redirectUrl) {
    var user = authResult.user;
    var credential = authResult.credential;
    var isNewUser = authResult.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser;
    var providerId = authResult.additionalUserInfo.providerId;
    var operationType = authResult.operationType;

    if(isNewUser)
    {
        //prompt user to enter a displayName to use with the application
    }
    // Do something with the returned AuthResult.
    // Return type determines whether we continue the redirect automatically
    // or whether we leave that to developer to handle.
    return true;
  },
```

},

Comment: Why don't you redirect the user after successful sign-up to an intermediate page/component to ask them for additional information?

Comment: That's what I ended up doing...but TBH, it would be a batter UI flow if you could determine if they are a new user during sign up and be able to insert some additional quesitons which you could use to complete the process. Redirecting to another page feels a bit awkward...but it works.

Comment: You don't have to redirect. On success, you can add a sign-in success callback which also provides a `UserCredential` (return false in that callback to disable the redirect). You can use that to check if the user is new or not and follow up with additional questions.